# Deserializing json with gson and retrofit

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm currently trying to deserialize a json object that contains hundreds of objects with identical structures, like this:

```
“data”: {
    “1” {
        “id” : 1
        “name” : “sample”
        },
        …
    “1000” {
        “id” : 1000
        “name” : “sample”
        }
}
```

How would i go about doing this with gson, retrofit and rxjava? The only way I can think of is by doing the following which seems impractical.

```
public class Data {

    @SerializedName(“1”)
    private Item _1;
    …
    @SerializedName(“1000”)
    private Item _1000;

    Item getItem_1() {
        return _1;
    }

    void setItem_1(Item _1) {
        this._1 = _1;
    }
    …
    Item getItem_1000() {
        return _1000;
    }

    void setItem_1000(Item _1000) {
        this._1000 = _1000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than creating a class for `"data"`, use `Map<String, Item>`. All the `"1"` ... `"1000"` will be the map keys, and you can use them or just ignore them and use `Map.values()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should change structure of your json format. Use array(square brackets) instead of 1000 objects(curly brackets).

```
{
“items”: [
    {
    “id” : 1
    “name” : “sample”
    },
    …
    {
    “id” : 1000
    “name” : “sample”
    }
]
}
```

Then your classes would be as below:

```
class Data{
    Item[] items;

    Item getItem(int position){
        return items[position];
    }

}

class Item{
    int id;
    String name;
}
```